# ScrollViewer jumps to the top when TextBox child loses focus

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

I'm having a weird UI issue in my app, where a `ScrollViewer` jumps to the top as soon as a `TextBox` child loses focus. I've already tried to set `BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"` in the parent `ScrollViewer`, but that doesn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Here's a quick video that shows the problem I have:

[image: gif]

As you can see, every time the top `TextBox` is focused, the `ScrollViewer` jumps back to the top as soon as it loses focus (ie. whenever I tap on an item in the `ListView`s below. This also happen if I click on one of those `ComboBox` controls: the `ScrollViewer` still jumps back immediately.

This is the *general structure* of the contents of the `Popup` your're seeing:

```
<UserControl>
    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <!--Item name-->
        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
        <customControls:TextBoxActionButton/>
        <customControls:TextValidatorControl/>

        <!--Section selector-->
        <TextBlock Text="Section"/>
        <customControls:ComboBoxWithResetButton/>

        <!--Item GroupName-->
        <TextBlock Text="Group"/>
        <customControls:ComboBoxWithResetButton/>

        <!--Template based on-->
        <TextBlock Text="Based on"/>
        <customControls:ComboBoxWithResetButton/>

        <!--Icons list and description-->
        <TextBlock Text="Icon"/>
        <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>

        <!--Select color text-->
        <TextBlock Text="Select color"/>
        <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</UserControl>
```

I don't have any code that interacts with the parent `ScrollViewer`, which is in a completely different `UserControl`, along with the rest of the `Popup` UI (header, buttons at the bottom etc..).

I've also tried to subscribe to the `LosingFocus` event of the first `TextBox`, and to set `e.Handled = true;` from there, but that didn't work too.

Do you have any idea on why this is happening? And also, why doesn't the `BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"` property work in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell which control you have used as ScrollViewer‘s parent?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew It's a custom control that contains that header and the buttons you see at the bottom, but I've tried to just place the usercontrol described in the question directly inside a `Popup` > `Grid` > `ScrollViewer` tree and the problem is still there, so I can confirm the issue is not caused by the parent control I'm using. I've also tried to use a simple, plain `TextBox` and to remove that one with the cancel button as well as the text validator, same issue. The `ScrollViewer` jumps as soon as the `TextBox` loses focus in any way.

Comment: @Sergio0694, did you get this resolved?

Comment: Hi @CarloMendoza - unfortunately, I didn't. I pretty much gave up on this at this point, I chalked this up to some weird framework behavior I can't really seem to be able to counter in any way.
At least it's not like this is a show stopper bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `TextValidatorControl` which causes the `TextBox` to regain focus, because this does not seem to happen when the control is not there.

Please verify what happens if you actually enter a valid name. If the behavior stops, I would suggest you to invetigate or post the source code of `TextValidatorControl`, because it looks like the source of the problems.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I'll test this right away, I'm not sure I'm following though, how can you say that the `TextValidatorControl` is causing the `TextBox` to regain focus (as the visual state remains the "unfocused" one as far as I can tell)? Also, even if that were the case, why is the `ScrollViewer` jumping to the top, regardless of which control gets or loses focus, even after setting the `BringIntoViewOnFocusChange` property?

Comment: I am not sure, it is just my guess that the validator is at cause somehow, as I see the validation error to appear. As I didn't see its code, I cannot say for sure :-) . But it doesn't happen on my side when the validator is not there, so it might be the cause. Maybe if you could post the validator's code as well?

Comment: The `TextValidatorControl` is just a `TextBlock` with an icon, it binds to the `Text` property of the `TextBox` above and updates its UI as the text changes. Anyways, I've tried to remove that altogether, same exact issue. Also tried to replace the `RelativePanel` with a `StackPanel` (just to try), same issue. I really don't get it 

Comment: Oh that is very weird... I must try again to replicate this

Comment: Thanks! I'll also try to create a repro if I can, I really hope it's just a glitch in my XAML code and not something wrong with the framework